# Include CMake syntax highlighting in Highlight.JS

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

This has been going on for a while now, but I was just motivated enough today to raise the issue. See an answer I wrote here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68039135/2137996

I see "Not" and "if" highlighted (not sure why "Not" is highlighted, actually) inside of the comment, which gets no special treatment. It's especially bad if a single quote `'` is present in the comment (like "isn't") because then that opens a string that spans multiple lines (until the next `'`).

Here you can see the behavior when specifying `<!-- language: lang-cmake -->`:

```cmake
# Not sure if needed:
# set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
# set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR AMD64)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET x86_64-windows-gnu)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-fuse-ld=lld")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-fuse-ld=lld")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-fuse-ld=lld")
set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-fuse-ld=lld")
```

**Can CMake be added to highlight.js so snippets are easier to read?**

---

In response to the comments, with `<!-- language: lang-makefile -->` it looks like this:

```makefile
# Not sure if needed:
# set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
# set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR AMD64)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET x86_64-windows-gnu)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-fuse-ld=lld")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-fuse-ld=lld")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-fuse-ld=lld")
set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-fuse-ld=lld")
```

This is... fine. As a stopgap. It would be much better to fix the CMake formatting.

Comment: there is no lang-cmake highlighter available: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108 you get the best effort one and on that answer on main you might get lang-c due to the [tag:c] tag.

Comment: You can however use `make`, `makefile`, etc. which'll get you pretty close to what it's meant to be

Comment: SO's code syntax highlighting is done through [the highlight.js library](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js), so if you notice any issues with a specific highlighter, they're best reported by opening an issue on their GitHub repo. You can read more about our highlighting situation, and the full list of languages, over at [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109)

Comment: @zcoop98 Highlight.js works perfectly fine with cmake, it's SO's version that's outdated

Comment: @Nick I don't want to come across as pedantic; SO is on a pretty recent release of the library, `10.7.2`, which just came out in April. Since then, there's been a minor version and a new major version released, but both of those are [only ~2 weeks old](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/tags). The issue very likely has nothing to do with using an outdated version, and everything to do with SO not including all languages, which is the category CMake apparently falls into.

Comment: The current version of highlight.js used by Stack Exchange is publicly available in SE's [`highlightjs-loader.js` file](https://dev.sstatic.net/js/highlightjs-loader.en.js) linked in the Meta.SE FAQ.

Comment: Is there a formal process for requesting a new language be added to SO's HLJS? The `cmake` tag is pretty active.

Comment: @Nick - `makefile` is... fine. As a stopgap. It would be much better to fix the CMake formatting.

Comment: I've edited this question into a `feature-request` as per the advice in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109

Comment: Theoretically, I could set the default language hint for the [[tag:cmake]] tag to be `make`. (In practice, I cannot, because `lang-make`/`lang-makefile` is not one of the options there, because these UI controls haven't been updated since the switch to Highlight.JS.) But that doesn't help too much, since that question, like many others, will also have higher-impact tags like [[tag:c]] or [[tag:c++]] attached to it, which have their own highlighting hints. That means you have little choice but adding manual highlight hints to your code blocks. Then you can add whatever you want.

Comment: @AlexReinking FYI even with full support the given snippet would only have `set` added to the highlighting with proper support IIRC, constants remain unhighlighted by highlight.js

Comment: @CodyGray - that's true, but it doesn't address the fact that writing "lang-cmake" or `\`\`\`cmake` currently applies misleading highlighting.

Comment: Just for your information, Stack Exchange is *very* reluctant to add additional languages to their Highlight.JS distribution because it increases code size, and when you serve billions of these requests out each day, even a small increase matters. I don't know if CMake would meet whatever their internal decision threshold is, but I kind of doubt it. I think the Makefile formatting is the best you're going to reasonably get. There are other languages that end up formatting much worse, so if it came down to a head-to-head, I'd have to pick one of them for inclusion instead.

Comment: Right... And that's part of the brokenness of Stack Exchange's highlighting system. Not enough room in a comment to explain it particularly well. But... If I made the highlighting hint on the [[tag:cmake]] tag `lang-makefile`, then you could get that with `\`\`\`cmake`. The problem is that almost no one tags questions with only [[tag:cmake]]. There's virtually always going to be a language tag on there. And when there are multiple competing language hints specified, then it's going to fall back to using "default", which will *also* break the normal language code highlighting.

Comment: @CodyGray -- I'm not seeing a _downside_ to making the highlighting for the [cmake] tag `lang-makefile`. So what if a higher-priority tag co-occurs? For those (potentially few) questions where [cmake] wins, the highlighting is better. Seems like a strict improvement to me, even if not a very _big_ one.

Comment: The downside is that when you have [[tag:cmake]] with `lang-makefile` and [[tag:c]] with `lang-c`, it is my understanding that the system will choose `lang-default` for all snippets that don't have an explicitly-specified hint. And that will make the C snippets look a lot worse than if they'd been highlighted with `lang-c`.

Comment: @CodyGray - wow.

Comment: The canonical is (effectively) *[Goodbye, Prettify. Hello highlight.js! Swapping out our syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983)*. [Sample feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355370).

Comment: @Alex Welcome to the “Stack Exchange desperately needs to overhaul the tag-highlighter relationship” party. It’s really, really bad, all things considered. It feels to me like something that was “good enough” when first implemented, and then never improved over time… it desperately needs a refresh. I know there’s a feature request on MSE somewhere, but I don’t have the link handy atm.

Comment: Note: Currently, for the code block in this question which is using the `<!-- language: lang-cmake -->`, the HTML after highlight.js runs indicates that the actual syntax highlighting language used is `language-swift`. Interestingly, the HTML after highlight.js runs for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61244367/3773011), which explicitly indicates `lang-cmake` as the syntax highlighting language for the code block that begins with "`# CMakeLists.txt`", shows that the highlighting language that *actually* gets used is `language-scss`.