# Add lang-cmake as syntax highlighting for the cmake tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

I [guess](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408477) that `lang-cmake` became available on Stack Overflow only recently.

According to "[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371)", moderators can assign syntax highlighting languages to tags.

**I ask to assign `lang-cmake` to the [`cmake`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmake) tag.**

If there is a technical reason, please give me a short explanation.

Comment: Pre-emptively, just in case somebody thinks to close this as a dupe recommending updating highlight.js: CMake is [a language supported by highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) thus the request here is fine as per [the the instructions under "Requesting that Stack Exchange support a new language which is already supported by highlight.js"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109).

Comment: It's not in [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) so that's not possible unless Stack Exchange do some development work to add it.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362711/cmake-syntax-highlighting

Comment: The questions you've linked do **not** indicate that `lang-cmake` is available. They indicate it's been *requested*. `lang-cmake` is not included in the list of actually supported highlighting languages contained in [answer to: "What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?"](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/271271). So, it's not currently supported. In other words, what you're specifically asking for is currently not possible (not to mention that the list of available highlighters for tags would also need to be updated, as it allows selection only from a subset of the complete list).

Comment: As can be seen in the HTML after highlight.js runs for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61244367/3773011), which explicitly indicates `lang-cmake` as the syntax highlighting language for the code block that begins with "`# CMakeLists.txt`", the highlighting language that *actually* gets used is `language-scss`.